# How to render a custom block with variables from another custom block twig template

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-blocks, drupal-hooks

I have a custom block with some values I can access in twig template of that block. Let's say variable `product_type` and in same twig file I'm adding another view block like

```
{{ drupal_block('views_block:my-view-block_1', {product_type: 'clothes'}) }}
```

and for that block's hook

```
function myModule_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args){
// I want that "product_type" variable here in this hook
// because I want to add a filter here like this:
$view->display_handler->display['display_options']['filters']['field_product_type_target_id']['default_value'] = $product_type;
}
```

Above hook is being invoked but I cannot get `product_type` in hook function. I'm not sure if that is the correct way to do it but I really need to pass that value from first block to second block and use that value in second block to filter out results. It's been 2 days I'm trying to figure this out. Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter you pass to `drupal_block()` is block configuration, so you won't be able to get it in the `hook_views_pre_view()`.

Use `drupal_view()` instead, you will get `product_type` in `$args`:

```
{{ drupal_view(<view_id>, <display_id>, {product_type: 'clothes'}) }}
```